# C# LINQ - SkipWhile() in reverse, without calling Reverse()?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

In this code:

```
    for (e = 0; e <= collection.Count - 2; e++)
    {
        var itm = collection.Read()
        var itm_price = itm.Price

        var forwards_satisfied_row = collection
            .Skip(e + 1)
            .SkipWhile(x => x.Price < ex_price)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        var backwards_satisfied_row = collection
            .Reverse()
            .Skip(collection.Count - e)
            .SkipWhile(x => x.Price < ex_price)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Suppose the collection contains millions of items and a Reverse() is too expensive, what would be the best way to achieve the same outcome as 'backwards_satisfied_row' ?

Edit:
For each item in the collection, it should find the first preceding item that matches the SkipWhile predicate.
For context I'm finding the distance a price extrema (minima or maxima) is from a horizontal clash with the price. This gives a 'strength' value for each Minima and Maxima, which determines the importance of it, and to help marry it up with extremas of a similar strength.

Edit 2 
This chart shows the data in the reproc code below, note the dip in the middle at item #22, this item has a distance of 18.
Bear in mind this operation will be iterated millions of times.
So I'm trying not to read into memory, and to only evaluate the items needed. 
When I run this on a large dataset `r_ex` takes 5 ms per row, whereas `l_ex` takes up to a second.

[image]

It might be tempting to iterate backwards and check that way, but there could be millions of previous records, being read from a binary file.
Many types of searches like Binary search wouldn't be practical here, since the values aren't ordered.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var dict_dists = new Dictionary<Int32, Int32>();
            var dict = new Dictionary<Int32, decimal> {   
                {1, 410},{2, 474},{3, 431},
                {4, 503},{5, 461},{6, 535},
                {7, 488},{8, 562},{9, 508},
                {10, 582},{11, 522},{12, 593},
                {13, 529},{14, 597},{15, 529},
                {16, 593},{17, 522},{18, 582},
                {19, 510},{20, 565},{21, 492},
                {22, 544},{23, 483},{24, 557},
                {25, 506},{26, 580},{27, 524},
                {28, 598},{29, 537},{30, 609},
                {31, 543},{32, 612},{33, 542},
                {34, 607},{35, 534},{36, 594},
                {37, 518},{38, 572},{39, 496},
                {40, 544},{41, 469},{42, 511},
                {43, 437},{44, 474},{45, 404},
                {46, 462},{47, 427},{48, 485},
                {49, 441},{50, 507}};

            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= dict.Count - 2; i++)
            {
                var ele = dict.ElementAt(i);
                var current_time = ele.Key;
                var current_price = ele.Value;
                var is_maxima = current_price > dict.ElementAt(i + 1).Value;

                //' If ele.Key = 23 Then here = True
                var shortest_dist = Int32.MaxValue;
                var l_ex = new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>();
                var r_ex = new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>();

                if (is_maxima)
                {
                    l_ex = dict.Reverse().Skip(dict.Count - 1 - i + 1).SkipWhile(x => x.Value < current_price).FirstOrDefault();
                    r_ex = dict.Skip(i + 1).SkipWhile(x => x.Value < current_price).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                else
                { // 'Is Minima
                    l_ex = dict.Reverse().Skip(dict.Count - 1 - i + 1).SkipWhile(x => x.Value > current_price).FirstOrDefault();
                    r_ex = dict.Skip(i + 1).SkipWhile(x => x.Value > current_price).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                if (l_ex.Key > 0)
                {
                    var l_dist = (current_time - l_ex.Key);
                    if ( l_dist < shortest_dist ) {
                        shortest_dist = l_dist;
                    };
                }

                if (r_ex.Key > 0)
                {
                    var r_dist = (r_ex.Key - current_time);
                    if ( r_dist < shortest_dist ) {
                        shortest_dist = r_dist;
                    };
                }

                dict_dists.Add(current_time, shortest_dist);
            }

            var dist = dict_dists[23];
        }
```

Edit: As a workaround I'm writing a reversed temp file for the left-seekers.

```
    for (i = file.count - 1; i >= 0; i += -1)
    {
        file.SetPointerToItem(i);
        temp_file.Write(file.Read());
    }
```

Comment: System.Linq has an extension method [Enumerable.SkipLast<TSource>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skiplast?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it more efficient by selecting the precedent of each item in one pass. Lets make an extension method for enumerables that selects a precedent for each element:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectPrecedent<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> selector)
{
    T selectedPrecedent = default;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (selector(item)) selectedPrecedent = item;
        yield return selectedPrecedent;
    }
}
```

You could then use this method, and select the precedent and the subsequent of each element by doing only two [`Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse) operations in total:

```
var precedentArray = collection.SelectPrecedent(x => x.Price < ex_price).ToArray();
var subsequentArray = collection.Reverse()
    .SelectPrecedent(x => x.Price < ex_price).Reverse().ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
{
    var current = collection[i];
    var precedent = precedentArray[i];
    var subsequent = subsequentArray[i];
    // Do something with the current, precedent and subsequent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do `.Reverse()` and then `FirstOrDefault()`, just use `LastOrDefault()`. Instead of `Skip(collection.Count - e)` use `.Take(e)` elements

```
    var backwards_satisfied_row = collection
        .SkipWhile(x => x.Price < ex_price)   //Skip till x.Price < ex_price
        .Skip(e+1)                           //Skip first e+1 elements
        .LastOrDefault();                 //Get Last or default value
```

---

You can make your code more efficient by storing collection and then just get `FirstOrDefault()` and `LastOrDefault()` for `forwards_satisfied_row` and `backwards_satisfied_row` respectively.

like,

```
for (e = 0; e <= collection.Count - 2; e++)
{
    var itm = collection.Read()
    var itm_price = itm.Price
    var satisfied_rows = collection
        .SkipWhile(x => x.Price < ex_price)
        .Skip(e + 1)
        .ToList();

    var forwards_satisfied_row = satisfied_rows.FirstOrDefault();

    var backwards_satisfied_row = satisfied_rows.LastOrDefault();
}
```